# making call from gsm modem in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, gsm, serial-communication, telecommunication

I want to make a call from a GSM modem using C#. I have written the following code. but I am unable to make the call. Please tell what the mistake is. Also let me know how to handle the response in the code from the modem so that I can display a message like "call connecting" or "cannot connect".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    SerialPort po = new SerialPort();  
    po.PortName = "COM3";  
    po.BaudRate = int.Parse( "9600");  
    po.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");  
    po.Parity = Parity.None;  
    po.StopBits = StopBits.One;  
    po.ReadTimeout = int.Parse("300");  
    po.WriteTimeout = int.Parse("300");  
    po.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");  
    po.Open();  
    po.DtrEnable = true;  
    po.RtsEnable = true;  
    po.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);  
    po.Write("ATD9030665834;");  
}  
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)  
    {  
            //what to write here to display the response??    
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what is the return value of po.Open();? Is it success??

Comment: yes the port is opening. but executing this code is not giving any result

Comment: What you are recieving then? If Data is reaching to Modem, it will retrun "OK" or "NACK" or something like that? Which GSM Modem you are using? and Does it really require Handshaking (RTS-CTS)? Read datasheet. Also increase the Read timeout.

Comment: The modem is working fine in hyper terminal.I do not know how to handle the response in the code. Need help for the same so that i can know whether i am getting any response from the modem or not.

Comment: I am a newbee. The modem is made in my company itself. its tested with hyper terminal. But i do not have idea how to send these commands to the gsm modem in C# coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [code for making a call from gsm modem using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429540/code-for-making-a-call-from-gsm-modem-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Druid it was His question only! :P

Comment: @SwanandPurankar: So? Still a duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use port.WriteLine("ATD"+phno+";");

This will definitely solve your problem..

And to handle the response use port.ReadExisting() and compare with your requirement. As easy as that :)

Good luck..

Answer (score 1):

1. Make Sure whether you are configuring `po` same as Hyper-terminal as it is working with Hyperterminal.
   Hyper Terminal settings are usually like:
   [image: COM Port Settings]

If it has Flow Control as NONE then You don't need:

```
po.DtrEnable = true;         
  po.RtsEnable = true;
```

I don't find use of Setting encoding.

Most important thing You are forgetting is **Add "\r" at the end of Any AT Command**! Seems you haven't read AT Command list!

Comment: yes. I did give the same settings. but still it is not working. please give me sample code for making a call in C# code using AT command.

Comment: ATD+phnumber is what we give in hyper terminal. But how to give this command in C#...??? port.write(????)

Comment: Check: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com

Comment: got it. It works by giving  port.WriteLine("ATD"+phnumber+";");

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort po = new SerialPort();
            po.PortName = "COM10";
            po.BaudRate = int.Parse("9600");
            po.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
            po.Parity = Parity.None;
            po.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            po.ReadTimeout = int.Parse("300");
            po.WriteTimeout = int.Parse("300");
            po.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            po.Open();
            po.DtrEnable = true;
            po.RtsEnable = true;
            //po.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
           // po.Write("ATD01814201013;");
            po.WriteLine("ATD01"+textBoxPhoneNumber.Text+";"+Environment.NewLine);
        }
```